# fillna after groupby and filter in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to fill nan after `goupby` and `filter` in pandas. For example, I want to group by 'label' and filter whether there are both `nan` and not `nan`. If both conditions are satisfied, I will fill the `nan` with the value in the same category.

Here's what I'm working on so far:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'label':['a','a','b','b','c','c'],
                        'value':[nan,'a1','b1','b1',nan,nan]})

#I am trying to do
df.groupby('label')\
  .filter(lambda x:x.value.isna().values.any() and not x.value.isna().values.all())\
  .apply(lambda x:x.sort_values('value').value.ffill())
```

I use `sort_values` because I want to put `nan` at the end so that I can use `ffill()`
But I got an error there is no axis names value. I wonder where is wroing. Or is there better way to do this? And how can the filled data be assigned to the original dataframe?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do `groupby` then just do `fillna` , if all NaN, it will remain NaN

```
df.groupby('label').value.apply(lambda x : x.ffill().bfill())
0     a1
1     a1
2     b1
3     b1
4    NaN
5    NaN
Name: value, dtype: object
```